# How do I access my data from a class which in dart& put it into my widget

Tags: flutter, dart

**`I have created a class file which as follow:
**

```
class ExerciseTypes1 {
  final int id;
  final String title, description, image;
  final Map<String, dynamic> data;
  ExerciseTypes1(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.description,
      required this.image,
      required this.data});

  get exerciseNum => id;

  get isDone => false;
}

List<ExerciseTypes1> exercise = [
  ExerciseTypes1(
    id: 1,
    title: "AEROBICS",
    description: "Frequency : At least 3 days per week",
    image: "assets/images/aerobics.png",
    data: {
      '1': {
        'id': 1,
        'name': "SIDE LUNGE",
        'description': "",
        'image': "assets/images/running.png",
        'video': "assets/videos/aerobics/warmup1.mp4",
      },
      '2': {
        'id': 2,
        'name': "SKIER HOPS",
        'description': "",
        'image': "assets/images/bikining.png",
        'video': "assets/videos/aerobics/warmup2.mp4",
      },
      '3': {
        'id': 3,
        'name': "MARCHING WITH HIGH KNEES",
        'description': "",
        'image': "assets/images/water_aerobics.jpeg",
        'video': "assets/videos/aerobics/warmup3.mp4",
      },
      '4': {
        'id': 4,
        'name': "ARM CIRCLES",
        'description': "",
        'image': "D:/Dissertation/omkar/code/app/assets/images/chair.png",
        'video': "assets/videos/aerobics/warmup4.mp4",
      },
      '5': {
        'id': 5,
        'name': "ARM CIRCLES",
        'description': "",
        'image': "D:/Dissertation/omkar/code/app/assets/images/chair.png",
        'video': "assets/videos/aerobics/warmup5.mp4",
      },
      '6': {
        'id': 6,
        'name': "ARM CIRCLES",
        'description': "",
        'image': "D:/Dissertation/omkar/code/app/assets/images/chair.png",
        'video': "assets/videos/aerobics/warmup6.mp4",
      },
      '7': {
        'id': 7,
        'name': "ARM CIRCLES",
        'description': "",
        'image': "D:/Dissertation/omkar/code/app/assets/images/chair.png",
        'video': "assets/videos/aerobics/warmup7s.mp4",
      },
    },
  ),
}
```

**Now I wanted to access the data and put it to my widget. When i call this widget it should display the name & video from data. Below is the my widget code**

```
import 'package:app/pages/homepage/Appbar/all_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../../constant/colors.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class videoView extends StatefulWidget {
  final ExerciseTypes1 ex;
  final int index;
  const videoView({Key? key, required this.index, required this.ex})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<videoView> createState() => _videoViewState();
}

class _videoViewState extends State<videoView> {
  List<String> exerciseNames = [];
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _intializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    extractExerciseNames();
    int dataIndex = widget.ex.data.length;

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(
        widget.ex.data[(dataIndex + 1).toString()]?['video']);

    _intializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    _controller.setLooping(true);
  }

  void extractExerciseNames() {
    for (String key in widget.ex.data.keys) {
      exerciseNames.add(widget.ex.data[key]?['name'] ?? '');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    int dataIndex = widget.index;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: size.width * 1,
                height: size.height * 0.20,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: kPrimaryLightColor,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      dataIndex < exerciseNames.length
                          ? exerciseNames[dataIndex]
                          : '',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    FutureBuilder(
                      future: _intializeVideoPlayerFuture,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                          return AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Center(
                            child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                        _controller.pause();
                      } else {
                        _controller.play();
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(_controller.value.isPlaying
                      ? Icons.pause
                      : Icons.play_arrow))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

I need to call ExerciseTypes1 class into widget file which will help me to display both name & vido of that id.
E.g:
I f i call Aerobics Then it takes the lenght and creates widget according to the length.

but when i click on 1 widget it should display name:"side lunge" and its video as well as.

Comment: you don't have ListView and column has just 1 child